# Gnome Login - AD User Not Listed

Tags: authentication, active-directory, gnome

Im on a `Fedora` machine, that has a user that joined an `active directory` domain via the `realm` command.
But that user is not listed in the gnome login screen.

So I have to click `not listed`, type `myuser@mydomain` type the password and login.

The two local users I created are listed there.
Is there a way to make the user `myuser@mydomain` appear on `gnome login`?
That way I don't need to type the user name every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by going to gnome settings -> user -> enterprise login and login with the user that I did a `realm join` with before... but this time I entered the user and not the domain admin. Which is weird because the enterprise login should do the same as the `realm join` command.